# How to call vbscript from Install shield script

Tags: installshield-2015

i am new to this install shield environment. My requirement is that i want to execute the VB script at the end of installation. We can achieve this operation using Custom action feature in install shield. But i have to pass 2 parameters to VB script. To achieve that, I have created a setup.rul (install shield script) to call the VB script and pass the parameters. Here i need assistance on how to call the VB Script from Install shield script and to pass the parameters. Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to wrap your script in a setup.rul.

You can create directly a Visual Basic script action[image] (I would suggest Stored in binary table since it allows you to store it as a vbs file next to your ISM and so it's easier to maintain).

Inside your vbScript, you can use the `Session.Property("MyProperty")` method to recover and set properties from your msi.

N.B. If you plan using a deferred action, then the only property available will be "CustomActionData".